# Custom setter for C# model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

I don't know how to make custom setter for C# data model. The scenario is pretty simple, I want my password to be automatically encrypted with SHA256 function. SHA256 function works very well (I've used in in gazillion of projects before).

I've tried couple of things but when I run `update-database` it seems it's doing something recursively and my Visual Studio hangs (don't send error). Please help me understand how to make passwords be encrypted by default in model.

### Code with what I've already tried

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Password;
        }

        set
        {
            // All this code is crashing Visual Studio

            // value = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(value);
            // Password = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(value);
            // this.Password = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Seed

```
context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Username, new Administrator { Username = "admin", Password = "123" });
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the Accessor to itself? Password = XXX would recall the Set Accessor of Password, which would again recall it... If you let VS run long enough, I would guess you would get a stack overflow. Do you have an actual field to store your password?

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras indeed it does something recursively I suspect, but how can I make this work then?

Comment: What is the field you use to store your password? An accessor isn't a field, it's a method in disguise.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use a private member variable as a backing-field. this allows you to store the value separately and manipulate it in the setter.

Good information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    private string _password;

    [Required]
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this._password;
        }

        set
        {  
             _password = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(value);                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The get and set you're using actually create methods called `get_Password()` and `set_Password(password)`.

You'd want the actual password to be stored in a private variable. So, just having a private variable that gets returned and updated by those "methods" is the way to go.

```
public class Administrator
{
public int ID { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Username { get; set; }
[Required]
private string password;
public string Password
{
    get
    {
        return this.password;
    }

    set
    {
        this.password = Infrastructure.Encryption.SHA256(value);
    }
}
}
```